# How does Snapchat store its data?

Tags: database-design

I am a highschool student who is interested in developing apps and learning more about databases and servers, so please bear with me if this is the wrong place to ask or if it's a obvious answer.

I have developed a few small database iPhone apps with Parse.com, so what somewhat of an idea of how a database works. But of course, I'm sure that is nothing compared to a real database.

**My question is:** How does an app like Snapchat go about storing its data (do you think)?

Does it just have one huge table of all the images? Meaning when someone uploads and app, does it create an object/row in a large table with the picture, who sent it, recipients, date, etc.? And then when the user logs in, does the app query that large table for all objects in that large table that has the currently logged in users id associated with recipients?

Talking very high-level, conceptual. This is my thought of how it would work, but I know there is millions of pictures on Snapchat servers, so I'm not sure how the speed of querying a large table like that would work, or how else it would be organized.

Comment: I doubt they are using the one large table approach.  It would not be scalable at the level Snapchat requires.  I believe they would be using a NoSQL solution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) spread across many servers.

Comment: Not even maybe ( https://www.quora.com/What-technology-stack-does-Snapchat-use ) - Google Cloud Datastore.

Answer (score 2):

All good, future-proofed databases are normalised to some extent. Normalisation is described by Louis Davidson ~ Pro SQL Server 2008 Relational Database Design and Implementation as

> The process of normalization is really
>   quite straightforward: take entities that are complex and extract
>   simpler entities from them. The process continues until every table in
>   the database represents one thing and every column describes that
>   thing.

So based on your example I would imagine that the Snap Chat database (assuming that we are talking about OLTP model and not using NOSQL / BIGData) would have multiple entities, with each entity containing relevant data and be related to other entities via the appropriate relationship i.e. 1..Many, Many to Many etc. For example, a person entity might contain UserName and Password and be related to a loginToSite entity via a 1..M relationship. I suggest a 1..M relationship because one person can log in to the site multiple times but each login to site record will only be related to one user. If all attributes were stored in the a single entity then in this example the UserName and Password information would be duplicated per Login record and break the rules of normalisation. This would also lead to a database usability nightmare!!

Depending on business rules, and these would be questions you would have to ask snap chat. One user record might be related to one or many photo records or maybe one user can be related to one or many photo records and one photo record can be related to one or many user records. In this case, there would be a many to many relationship.

When thinking about database design it's important to first work out the conceptual design by talking with end users, reviewing reports / spread-sheets (anything containing data used by the end user) and generating an ERD. Then once the relationships have been agreed, all data to be stored captured and the ERD modelled you can move onto the physical side of things and work on performance, choosing data types, deciding on indexes etc...